# D3 Pie Legend is not showing

Tags: angular, d3.js

this d3 Pie chart is not showing legend, even try giving the `position:absolute` but still not showing.
But In console, its showing only first value of data.

```
this.svg = d3.select("#airlineChart").select("svg");
    this.svgLegend = this.svg.append("div").attr("class", "mainLegend")
    .attr("transform", `translate(${this.radius},${this.radius})`);
this.mainContainer = this.svg
      .append("g")
      .attr("transform", `translate(${this.radius},${this.radius})`);
    this.slices = this.mainContainer
          .selectAll("path")
          .remove()
          .exit()
          .data(this.pie(this.airline_tonnage))
          .enter()
          .append("g")
          .append("path")
          .attr("d", this.arc)
          .attr("fill", (d, i) => this.color(i));

          this.svgLegend
          .data(this.airline_tonnage)
          .append("rect") // make a matching color rect
          .attr("class", "pieLegend")
          .attr("width", 10)
          .attr("height", 10)
          .attr("fill", (d, i) => this.color(i))
          .attr("stroke", "black")
          .style("stroke-width", "0px");

          // append the text element
          this.svgLegend
          .data(this.pie(this.airline_tonnage))
          .append("text") // add the text
          .text(d => d.data.name)
          .style("font-size", 12)
          .attr("y", 10)
          .attr("x", 11);
```

Banging my head, what causing to hide this legend.
Any Solution.

Comment: can you add a link to your code, a stackblitz

Comment: `this.svg.append("div")` this wont work i think, do not include html tags inside an svg. change it to rect or a <g> if you want not to show it

Comment: @bubbles, you are right, I changed to `rect` and its showing, now the data value  is not visible :(

Comment: i need the whole code for this

Comment: actually I am fetching from lot of places , is there any way to check like teamvier?

Comment: build a json mocks

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-joe1qh

Comment: sorry your exemple is not working, could you fix it please